# A way to automate cloudformation templates deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to automate cloudformation templates deployment? I mean it would be awesome if I just push the changes in the code and somebody looking for those changes in the code and once they appear - deploy the updated template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with AWS Code Pipeline !

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html

> With AWS CloudFormation and AWS CodePipeline, you can use continuous delivery to automatically build and test changes to your AWS CloudFormation templates [...]
>
> AWS CodePipeline has built-in integration with AWS CloudFormation, so you can specify AWS CloudFormation-specific actions, such as creating, updating, or deleting a stack, within a pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

**[CodePipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html)** is a great way to do what you're looking for.

At Giftbit we do this is by having a **Github Repo** that has our **CloudFormation template** in it.

When we want to make a change, we make the changes on a **branch** in the repo, and create a pull request into the **`staging`** branch. **CodePipeline** monitors the **`staging`** branch then automates a **CodeBuild** to validate the templates, package any SubStacks, then creates a Change Set and Executes it.

Below are have some examples to help **Quick Start** anyone interested:

- [Continuous Integration CloudFormation Template Example](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml)
- [Serverless Application Model (SAM)](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/sam.yaml) that gets deployed

Comment: What about service role for CloudFormation? When I create the pipeline it asks me on 4th step (with CloudFormation selected as deployment provider to select the service role). I could created one, but which permissions should I provide to that role?

Comment: Here's an example of one for deploying a lambda function https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/496200ce05992db72d7af94e201ad01b0c11cb0e/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml#L187. The Big question is, what does the template you're deploying do? It needs permission for that. So if it creates a bucket, it should have `s3:CreateBucket` and `s3:DeleteBucket`. If it creates role, give it permission to create and delete roles. It's always important to make sure your role can undo what it does, so it can role back.